# looping through sheets to delete a particular range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all my sheets to delete all content in I20 to I30
and J20 to J30

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Select
    sh.Range("I20 : J30").Select
    Selection.ClearContens
Next sh
```

It returns method of selection error

Comment: Do you mean `ClearContents`?

Comment: You can replace all 3 lines with `sh.Range("I20:J30").ClearContents`  No need for any selection

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me with a few minor adjustments:

When you define a range (`sh.Range("I20 : J30").Select` in your case) do not put spaces before and after the semicolon, instead use: `sh.Range("I20:J30").Select`

Secondly, as braX noted, `"ClearContents"`.

I hope this resolves your issue,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

...and while you're at it: there's no need to select anything.

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Range("I20:J30").ClearContents
Next sh
```